# My VBA code to Save as a PDF wont work. Can someone read it and see what I might be doing wrong?

Tags: pdf, vba

```
Sub SaveAsPDF()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    NewFN = "C:\Users\Brock\Desktop\MPI\Financials\" & Range("b10").Value & ".pdf"
    Dim ActiveWorksheet As Variant
    ActiveWorksheet = "sheet1"
    ActiveWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFN, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Error 424 pops up every time. The highlighted part is:

```
ActiveWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=NewFN, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I can't figure out what the issue is for the life of me. I'm learning VBA coding as I go, so I don't know what many things mean!

Answer (score 3):

`ActiveWorkSheet` must be a worksheet or must be wrapped by `WorkSheets()` when using it as a string.

As a Worksheet:

```
Dim ActiveWorksheet As WorkSheet
Set ActiveWorksheet = WorkSheets("sheet1")
```

As is:

```
Dim ActiveWorksheet As Variant
ActiveWorksheet = "sheet1"
Worksheets(ActiveWorksheet).ExportAsFixedFormat ...
```

You are getting the error because:

```
"sheet1".ExportAsFixedFormat
```

Does not work in vba.